# Как создать хранилище параметров на С?

Tags: c++, c, stm32, stm32cubeide

Всем добрый день, вопрос предельно глупый, но у меня совсем нету опыта в *С* (STM32CubeIDE).

**ЗАДАЧА:**

Микроконтроллер обрабатывает разноплановые команды (протокол MAVLINK) компьютера. Одна из команд запрашивает список из 14-ти параметров конфигурации программы.

Параметр имеет:

- ИМЯ      (char до 15 символов),
- ЗНАЧЕНИЕ (float),
- ТИП      (uint8_t!! по протоколу MAVLINK),

ДОП: КОЛ-ВО всех параметров(uint16_t).

**ВОПРОС:**

- Как должно выглядеть 'хранилище' сохраняющее 3 характеристики для каждого параметра?

Данная структура должна быть заполнена вручную для простоты. К тому же нужны функции взаимодействия: ГЕТТЕР/СЕТТЕР/Подсчет кол-ва параметров.

Если бы я писал на С++, задача была бы простейшей. Но я никогда не объединял С/С++ блоки. В теории я понимаю как этого добиться (через структуру с поведением класса), но хотелось бы узнать есть ли каноничное решение на С.

Comment: Так вы же сами ответили на свой вопрос: заводим структуру, пишем функции для установки и получения значения. Функции внутрь структур обычно не записывают (хотя такое и возможно), а просто первым параметром геттера/сеттера передаём указатель на структуру.

Comment: Если-бы вы сделали минимальный C++ проект и показали, то легко бы вам переписали всё на Си. Вам нужно только Си или дружно вместе с Си++ ?

Comment: ¿Как можно написать что-то на С++, когда совсем нету опыта в С?

Comment: @maestro, хах, простите я немного сглупил. Да, ваш вариант в итоге и сделал. Я просто сперва написал на плюсах простой объект отигрывающий поль хранилища, а после зациклился на вопросе, как повторить ООП в среде где ООП нету. Извиняюсь перед всеми за потраченное время